# C - fwrite writes invalid data

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, fread, stdio

Here is how the data is written:

```
FILE* f = fopen(FILENAME, "ab");

if(ferror(f) != 0) {
    printf("fopen failed %d\n", ferror(f));
}

size_t written = 0;

written = fwrite(&key, sizeof(key), 1, f);
if(written != 1) {
    printf("fwrite wrote %d elements, should have been %d\n", written, 1);
}

written = fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, f);
if(written != 1) {
    printf("fwrite wrote %d elements, should have been %d\n", written, 1);
}

if(ferror(f) != 0) {
    printf("fwrite failed %d\n", ferror(f));
}

fclose(f);
```

Here is how the data is read:

```
FILE* f = fopen(FILENAME, "rb");

if(ferror(f) != 0) {
    printf("fopen failed %d\n", ferror(f));
}

uint64_t key = 0;
uint64_t value = 0;
size_t read = 0;

while(!feof(f)) {
    read = fread(&key, sizeof(key), 1, f);
    if(read != 1) {
        printf("fread read %d elements, should have been %d\n", read, 1);
    }

    read = fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, f);
    if(read != 1) {
        printf("fread read %d elements, should have been %d\n", read, 1);
    }

    if(ferror(f) != 0) {
        printf("fread failed %d\n", ferror(f));
    }

    if(key == 0 || value == 0) {
        printf("fread output was key = %llu, value = %llu\n", k, value);
    }

    if(key == arg) {
        fclose(f);
        return value;
    }
}

printf("EOF reached, returning 0\n");
fclose(f);
return 0;
```

Now here is the puzzle: none of the printf debugging / error statements are triggered. As far as I'm concerned, I'm opening and closing the files correctly, I'm writing and reading the correct amount of (right sized) elements and neither are there any miscellaneous errors output.

However, the values read sometimes differ from the values written. This happens only rarely, perhaps once every 30 - 50 runs but the effects in this case are catastrophical because in my case it results in my program crashing. Here's some output from my debug statements directly outside of the functions (there should be no code that could alter the values in any way):

```
Saving key-value pair to store failed, wrote value 1930602754145344693, read value 7983440653331291317
File contents:
key 32385216, value 10451404324075904545
key 32385152, value 8261841165554445677
key 32384944, value 7948309595355207668
key 32384320, value 79834406533311291317
```

There were no duplicate keys (or values) in the file.

Can you give me any guidance how to debug a problem like this? To me it looks like the problem is outside my program but I'm not sure if that can be the case. My OS is Windows 7 x64 and I'm writing to my system SSD disk which should not be faulty in any way (and I think the file I'm writing to is actually cached in the RAM by Windows all the time because of the frequent accesses).

Comment: Is this actually the code you're running? The messages in the code do not appear to match the messages in the output. Also, compilable examples would be good - we don't know, for example, the types of the variables involved in the write example.

Comment: Another tip, outputting the values in hex would probably be much more useful for debugging. That will help identify endianness issues, shifting, truncation, etc. that are much harder to see in decimal.

Comment: Yes, this is the code I am running. The two code examples provided the exact bodies of my own read & write functions. As I said, none of the debug statements you can see in the posted code are triggered. The messages in the output are additional checks outside those two functions. Both variables (key and value) in the write example are int64_t.

Comment: Specifically, in your failure message the corresponding hex values are `1ACA E0F9 E339 5CB5` and `6ECA E0F9 E339 5CB5` - each byte is the same except for the first. Possibly you have memory corruption elsewhere in your code. It's pretty unlikely that `fread`/`fwrite` corrupt one byte out of 8.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thank you so much for your comment. Actually I'm doing a fair share of pointer magic I probably shouldn't be doing elsewhere in my code so your proposed scenario seems to be pretty likely. How do I manage to (sometimes) corrupt exactly the values I'm writing and have no other ill effects - I have no idea. But I guess I have to find out somehow.

Comment: `fwrite(&key, sizeof(key), 1, f);` looking this call, you are writing only one object. *They return the number of objects read or written.  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short object count (or zero).* extract from the man page for `fwrite()` and `fread()`. So if `fwrite()` succeed, 1 will be returned, that is why the debugging information would not be printed.

Comment: Minor: Rather than `while(!feof(f))`, break from the loop when `read == 0`

Comment: @Kira Not sure what you're trying to say. `fwrite` is being called with some item size, and `1` for the number of items. If the `fwrite` call succeeds it will have to return `1` and if it does not succeed it will have to return `0`. The `written != 1` check will thus work as intended.

Comment: @AndrewMedico indeed, I totally misread the question.